# NotifyIcon + NotificationWindow

Tags: c#, notifyicon

I am using NotifyIcon plus the Notification Window (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277584/Notification-Window). All works well however I did not manage to show notification windows, a window appears but without any content and if I click it the application crashes. Here is my code:

```
namespace test
{
    public class NotificationIcon : ServiceBase
    {
        private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger (typeof(NotificationIcon));

        private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
        private ContextMenu notificationMenu;

        #region Initialize icon and menu
        public NotificationIcon(Boolean isService)
        {
            if(isService)
            {
                ....

            } else
            {
                Logger.Info("Start");

                notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;
                notificationMenu = new ContextMenu(InitializeMenu());

                popup = new NotificationWindow.PopupNotifier();

                ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(NotificationIcon));

                notifyIcon.ContextMenu = notificationMenu;
                notifyIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(doubleClick);

                Thread t = new Thread(notificationThread);
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                t.Start();
            }
        }      

        private NotificationWindow.PopupNotifier popup;


        private void notificationThread()
        {
            NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut);

            while (true)
            {
                server.WaitForConnection();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);

                try
                {

                    while(true)
                    {

                        if(!tokens[4].Equals("A") && !tokens[4].Equals("B"))
                        {
                            showTip(tokens[4], 
                                    tokens[2] + tokens[3]);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                     Logger.Error("Unable to receive pipe message from client", e);

                     // Create a new pipe stream
                     server.Close();
                     server = new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut);

                } finally
                {
                    if(server.IsConnected) { server.Disconnect(); }
                }
            }    
        }

        private void showTip(String title, String msg)
        {
            //notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(5000, title, msg, ToolTipIcon.Info);

            Logger.Info("Show popup");

            popup.TitleText = title;
            popup.ContentText = msg;

            // This kills the application
            popup.Popup();  

            Logger.Info("Done");
        }

        #region Main - Program entry point
        /// <summary>Program entry point.</summary>
        /// <param name="args">Command Line Arguments</param>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {

                if (Environment.UserInteractive)
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                    NotificationIcon notificationIcon = new NotificationIcon(false);
                    Application.Run()
                    notificationIcon.notifyIcon.Dispose();

                } else
                {
                    Logger.Info("Start Service");

                    ServiceBase.Run(new NotificationIcon(true));
                }

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Error("Error during service start", e);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I got a partial workaround if add a while(true) Application.DoEvents() after the popup() call. However I want a clean solution